# Increment ++ Operator overloading in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I want to increment the next node by changing the `current = current->next` to `current++` but it does not work. So I try to use an iterator class to perform operator overloading. But there is a bug, I am not sure what happens here:

```
struct node{
    int value;
    node *next;
}

class Iterator{
    public:
        Iterator();
        Iterator(node *);
        Iterator operator++(int);
    private:
        node *point;
};

Iterator::Iterator(){
    point = NULL;
}

Iterator::Iterator(node *current){
    point = current;
}

Iterator Iterator::operator++(int u){
    point = point->next;
    return *this;
}
```

and the print is like:

```
class linkedList{
   public:
      void print() const;
   protected:
      node *first;
}

void linkedList::print()const{
   node *current = first;
   Iterator p = Iterator(current);

   while(current != NULL){
       cout << current->value << " ";
       p++;
   }
}
```

but it turns out there is a bug

Comment: Why do you expect calling `p++` to affect the value of `current`? `p` has its own `node*`, `point`, which starts equal to `current` but then changes.

Comment: You need to add operators  `->` and `!=` to your iterator class to make iterating by `for (Iterator it(first), end; it != end; ++it)  std::cout << it->value << '\n';`

Comment: "it turns out there is a bug" what does that mean? Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question and explain what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a loop that half uses a pointer and half uses an iterator. Pick one or the other. For instance with an iterator

```
Iterator p = Iterator(current);
while (current != Iterator()){
    cout << p->value << " ";
    p++;
}
```

Now this loop means you also have to overload `operator!=` and `operator->` for your iterator. It would also make sense to overload `operator==` and `operator*`.

Comment: Note that this code is creating a new temporary `Iterator` object on every loop iteration, which should be avoided.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would expect that to be optimised away. Even if not this iterator is about as cheap to construct as could be.

Comment: perhaps, perhaps not, it depends on the compiler. But there is really no need to be repetitive on purpose if you don’t have to be. A simple tweak will suffice: `Iterator p(current), end; while (p != end) { ... p++; }`